# Laravel-5.5:Why redirected if I use in rules 'required'?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have simple web routes.

#### Code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'inbox', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/compose', 'InboxController@compose')->name('compose');
    }); 
});
```

And I have simple method `compose()`

#### Code:

```
public function compose(InboxRequest $request)
{   
    return view('compose');
}
```

And InboxRequest file.

#### Code

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'receiver' => 'required'
   ];
}
```

My HTML form with fields

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('compose') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">To</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputEmail1" class="form-control" name="receiver" value="{{old('receiver')}}">

    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">From</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="cc" class="form-control" name="sender" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" disabled="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" name="subject" value="{{old('subject')}}">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If I use `email|exists:users,email` working but in `required` redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Laravel 5.5** to all routes already connected `middleware['web']`. If in in routes already have needed middleware then you should in the file `web.php` divide the route  to : `POST` and `GET`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'inbox', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/compose', 'InboxController@compose')->name('compose'); 
    Route::post('/compose', 'InboxController@send')->name('send');
});
```

HTML form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('send') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">To</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputEmail1" class="form-control" name="receiver" value="{{old('receiver')}}">

    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">From</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="cc" class="form-control" name="sender" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" disabled="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" name="subject" value="{{old('subject')}}">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And InboxRequest file, you set `authorize()` `return true;`

```
       /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public function rules()
        {
           return [
              'receiver' => 'required'
          ];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation):

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location.

Also, you shouldn't apply `web` middleware in 5.5 manually.

Comment: I must delete `'middleware' => ['web']` in route yes? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @MaxNet yes, you need to remove it because it is applied for all routes in the `web.php` already.

Comment: what I must do for work `required` in `InboxRequest` say please step by step?

Comment: With devide route all works: `Route::get('/compose', 'InboxController@compose')->name('compose');
 Route::post('/compose', 'InboxController@send')->name('send');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't send 'receiver' param to route.

InboxRequest is validation for request params and this Request  you don't send receiver.

call /compose route with get or post receiver data.

example: /compose?receiver=test

Comment: I already send  `receiver` field name with post using html form to my controller. And if I not be give this field then why work `email|exists:users,email` rules?

Comment: Because your email field in this sample is not required and is optional so if you send email this rule will be work and if don't send it this rule will not be check

Comment: I could not explain it to you. Now I will update the question and you all understand

Comment: I create a project for you and write your example and call you route. In your case my answer is true. If you are in route /A and so get to route /inbox/compose this route will be call as a get method and this case you must send receiver param. for see errors after redirect use this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: I divided the router into two parts. POST and GET and now all works

Comment: `Route::get('/compose', 'InboxController@compose')->name('compose');
 Route::post('/compose', 'InboxController@send')->name('send');`

Comment: It work because get route don't have Request validation or you send receiver param to it.